# Going for a wholefor loop round vs getting the list sliced : Which solution is more efficient?

Tags: python

So here's two simple snippets of code :

```
myList = [17, 3, 11, 5, 1, 9, 7, 15, 13]
largest = myList[0]
for i in myList:
    if i > largest:
        largest = i

print(largest)
```

It's clear that this program tries to get the maximum value of the list, but the for loop will start from the first element which is 17 ( i'm not trying to say that we shoudln't even get into the loop, i know we can you a loop), now here's the second snippet of code :

```
myList = [17, 3, 11, 5, 1, 9, 7, 15, 13]
largest = myList[0]

for i in myList[1:]:
    if i > largest:
        largest = i

print(largest)
```

This one's result is the same as the first , but there's a slight difference, that's to say, this second one doesn't perform an unnecessary comparison, but it slice almost all of the list's elements

The question is: which of these two actions consumes more computer resources - just one comparison, or slicing almost all of a list's elements?

Comment: Why don't you just run it and see for yourself?

Comment: In linear algorithms, these microoptimalizations do not really count.

Comment: Note that the "proper" and likely fastest way of doing this is ``largest = max(myList)``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, yes, I already know about the max function, thank you!

Comment: Also i have an old computer so somtimes he gives me right timing sometimes not

Comment: @nagyl like i've already said, i've an old computer, and i think that these microoptimilizations do count

Comment: @SafwenSoker its not about the computer, because each op takes some time, lets call it  `t`. If you have a loop that runs exactly `n*t*c` clock cycles, where `c` is some constant (Because python commands will be compiled into machine code, which is likely to be more than one clock cycle). Note that `t` remains the same for each operation. Your code runs `(n-1)*t*c` clock cycles, which really does not count, since `n` can be a very large number. Also an old machine should run this code way faster than you would notice any difference. If you need faster solutions, please look at data structures.

Comment: @nagyl, Understood, Thank you very much!